# Customise and remove unrequired fields from Zalando problem reponse body in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am facing an issue where I throw a Zalando problem error on validation of a field in Spring boot. I customized the response body by extending from AbstractThrowableProblem by invoking the super constructor and passing the required fields.

I set the Status field as BAD_REQUEST and then I pass my custom object to the 'parameters' argument which takes a Map.

Till this point, it's fine. I get a 400 BAD_REQUEST Http status code along with the custom map object in the response body.

The problem now here is that a 'status' field also shows up in the response body which is coming since I set it while calling the super constructor.

***I want to know how to just have 400 in the Http Status code section only and not in the response body. I just need my custom map object in the response body.***

```
Actual response:
Response Http status code - 400 BAD_REQUEST
Response body -
{
"status": 400,
"appError": "The name field that you filled in has Invalid special characters."
}

Expected response:
{
"appError": "The name field that you filled in has Invalid special characters."
}
```

The Zalando problem class I wrote is as below:

```
class MyAppZalandoProblem extends AbstractThrowableProblem {

Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("appError", "The name field that you filled in has Invalid special characters.");

MyAppZalandoProblem() {
 super(null, null, Status.BAD_REQUEST,  null, null, null, myMap);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

You simply can't.

It's not the recommended way to return an HTTP problem: [**RFC7807**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807)

By the way, The Zalando Problem library maintainers [**have refused to allow such customization**](https://github.com/zalando/problem/issues/245).

Comment: Thanks a lot Phil. This solves my search.